# How to use Laxxx.js to animate boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to figure out how I can use Laxxx.js with my html section with two boxes.Here is my code.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <title>Sidebar Navigation</title>
</head>

<body>
<section id="about">
        <div class="page-num">
            <h1>01</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <div class="box1"></div>
            <div class="box2" data-lax-preset="spin-180"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <h1>About</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quisquam alias recusandae tenetur impedit similique dolore, rem molestias illo incidunt ipsum ipsa omnis odit, placeat tempore sapiente aliquid unde. Quaerat, architecto ex sit possimus commodi distinctio enim. Maxime, odit iste animi ut et iure, eius error.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

   <script src="node_modules/lax.js/lib/lax.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            lax.setup() // init

            document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
                lax.update(window.scrollY)
            },false)
            console.log('hey');

        }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

scss

```
#about {
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;


  .left {
    width: 40%;
    position:relative;

      .box1{
        position:absolute;
        top: 20% ;
        left:20%;
        z-index:0;
        width:400px;
        height:400px;
        border:30px solid yellow;
        overflow:hidden;
        transform: rotateZ(65deg);
      }
      .box2{
        position:absolute;
        top: 30%;
        left:10%;
        z-index:0;
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        border:30px solid red;
        overflow:hidden;

      }
  }
  .right {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10vh 20vh;
    // position:relative;
    h1 {
      font-size: 3vw;
      margin: 0;
    }
    p {
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      line-height: 28px;
    }
  }
}
```

I guess I have followed al the steps on documentation however I get no amination on scroll and no error on console as well.

And here is the github documentation for laxxx.js https://github.com/alexfoxy/laxxx

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add the `lax` class

```html
<div class="lax box2" data-lax-preset="spin-180"></div>
```